# Abrir página em PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando abrir uma página com um link dentro da outra, mas ela não carrega, e aparentemente parece estar tudo ok.

```
 <?php
//pagina principal

echo "<a href=\"principal.php\">Link1<?</a>";
echo "<a href=\"principal.php?a=pagina2.php\">Link2<?</a>";
echo "<a href=\"principal.php?a=pagina3.php\">Link3<?</a>";

@$pagina = $GET['a'];

if(isset($pagina)){
    include $pagina;
    }else{
    echo "Bem vindo a página principal";
    }
?>
```

Não aparece o conteúdo da página 2 e nem da página 3, o que poderia ser? Grato desde já

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro básico está na falta do underline entre o `$` e o `GET`: seria `$_GET` em vez de <s>`$GET`</s>.

Outro erro é que você está colocando um sinal de abertura de tag em `<?` antes de fechar as tags `<a>`, embora isso o navegador corrija automaticamente fechando as tags `<a>`.

Seu código seria:

```
<?php
//pagina principal

echo "<a href=\"teste2.php\">Link1</a>";
echo "<a href=\"teste2.php?a=pagina2.php\">Link2</a>";
echo "<a href=\"teste2.php?a=teste3.php\">Link3</a>";

@$pagina = $_GET['a'];

if(isset($pagina)){
    include $pagina;
    }else{
    echo "Bem vindo a página principal";
}
?>
```

Comment: Show, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

O seu código possui alguns erros na declaração dos links.

Você pode também pegar o conteúdo do `else` em seu código e criar uma página padrão e associar a condição do `if` na própria variável `$pagina`. Veja:

```php
<?php
echo "<a href=\"principal.php\">Link1</a>";
echo "<a href=\"principal.php?a=pagina2.php\">Link2</a>";
echo "<a href=\"principal.php?a=pagina3.php\">Link3</a>";

$pagina = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : 'pagina-padrao.php';

if( file_exists( $pagina ) ) {
    include $pagina;
}
else {
    echo "Erro 404 página não existe";
}
```